# OSGi: Loading a super class with a different version than the child Class is statically wired to

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, bundle

I have a situation: Class B in it's own Bundle (say Bundle-B-1.0.0). Class A is in Bundle-A.1.0.0) and the relationship between A and B is:

```
public class B extends A {
    public B(){
      super();
    }
}
```

I am trying to load class B in a different ClassLoader C that has visibility of Class A', which is same as Class-A but in a different(higher) version of Bundle-A.2.0.0.

When I create an instance of Class B (from same Bundle-B.1.0.0)  using ClassLoader C and via Reflection, how do I ensure that it refers/uses class A' from Bundle-A.2.0.0 (the higher versioned bundle) when it calls super()?

The requirement that I am trying to fulfill is that Class B can/should be able to refer A or A' on demand during its own instantiation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. Bundle B will be wired to import from either A or A' but you cannot dynamically switch between the two.

Comment: Agreed. After a bit of trials, I tried reloading the class bytecode using the ClassLoader C (calling definClass() via Reflection) and that does the trick.

Comment: Then you have created B' (which extends A'). These are all different classes from the VM's point of view.

Comment: That's correct too. Now, that takes me back to the original requirement - how would one correctly design a solution for this problem.

Comment: Anand: that would depend what problem you were originally trying to solve, and there's no information on that in your question. In general, situations where you need to dynamically choose between multiple possibilities call for the use of OSGi Services. But you should give up on modelling with inheritance.